# Printing how many times an inner nested loops occurs when loops have step sizes > 1?

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to print the number of occurrences an inner loop happens as a sequence from `0..n`.

Consider the below code:

```py
top = 10
step = 1
for i in range(0, top, step):
  for j in range(0, top, step):
    print((i*top)+j)
```

This will print `0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99` which is fine, but the step size is `1`. What if the step size is a larger number?

```py
top = 10
step = 2
for i in range(0, top, step):
  for j in range(0, top, step):
    print((i*top)+j)
```

This doesn't print `0, 1, 2, ..., 23, 24`. However, the below does:

```py
top = 10
step = 2
idx = 0
for i in range(0, top, step):
  for j in range(0, top, step):
    print(idx)
    idx += 1
```

Using step size of `3` prints `0, 1, 2, ..., 14, 15`. Step size of `4` prints `0, 1, 2, ..., 7, 8`. And so on.

Is there a way to do this without using an extra variable or magic numbers? Isn't the number of times `idx += 1` is called here just a function of `i`, `j`, `top` and `step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of iterative steps mathematically.

You know the starting point of the range (`0`) and the ending point (`top`). When the step is non-zero you increment by step each time. Each iteration tests whether your current value has reached the bound or not. If it has not reached the bound the iteration continues.

When the step is `1`, it is very easy to calculate the number of iterations, simply subtract the upper bound from the lower bound. Example: `10 - 0 = 10` iterations (`[0, 1, 2 ..., 9]`).

When the step is non-zero we have to consider that each step moves us more quickly to the bound. Example:

- Upper_bound 10
- lower_bound 0
- step 2.

We need to get from 0 to 10 by 2s.
We initialize some counter `i` to 0. We compare that counter to the `upper_bound` (10). First iteration we check is 0 < 10. This is `True`, so we `yield` 0 and increment `i` by `step` (2).

| i | Comparison | Result of Comparison | Value Yielded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `0 < 10` | True | Yes |
| 2 | `2 < 10` | True | Yes |
| 4 | `4 < 10` | True | Yes |
| 6 | `6 < 10` | True | Yes |
| 8 | `8 < 10` | True | Yes |
| 10 | `10 < 10` | False | No |

This range yields 5 values. We could discover this by converting the range into a list then getting the length of it. However, we can also calculate the number of values based on just `upper_bound`, `lower_bound`, and `step`. We know we need to traverse from `upper_bound` to `lower_bound`, and we can determine how many iterations we need by dividing the range to traverse by the step.

`(upper_bound - lower_bound) / step`

`(10 - 0) / 2 = 5`

This matches our found values `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`.

Things get tricky when the bound is not neat. Such as an odd upper bound with an even step. Example:

- upper_bound 15
- lower_bound 0
- step 2.

In this case, (15 - 0) / 2 is 7.5.

The question is then will range do 7 or 8 iterations?

| i | Comparison | Result of Comparison | Value Yielded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `0 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 2 | `2 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 4 | `4 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 6 | `6 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 8 | `8 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 10 | `10 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 12 | `12 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 14 | `14 < 15` | True | Yes |
| 16 | `16 < 15` | False | No |

The answer is 8, since current step will compare 14 to 15. Since 14 is less than 15, the value 14 is yielded. The iteration does not terminate until `i` becomes 16 and breaks the less than `upper_bound` requirement.

In terms of maths, we can say that the number of iterations is always the next whole number after the division, or the ceiling of the division operation.

`ceiling((upper_bound - lower_bound) / step)`

We can use `ceil` from `math` to ensure that the division always rounds up.

Now that we can calculate the number of iterations of any range based on the `upper_bound`, `lower_bound`, and `step`, we can start to look at how to calculate the number of iterations of a nested loop.

In this case the inner and outer loops run the same number of times, and the inner loop runs the same amount every iteration (this may not always be the case).
However, in this case, if the inner loop runs 5 times, the outer loop will also run 5 times. 5 sets of 5 iterations is 25 iterations in total. This is the direct product of the number of inner iterations and outer iterations.

`total_iterations = outer_iterations * inner_iterations`

Which, in this particular case, equates to:

`total_iterations = (ceiling((upper_bound - lower_bound) / step))^2`

All together your program could look something like:

```py
import math


def main():
    range_lower_bound = 0
    range_upper_bound = 15
    range_step = 2

    # Calculate the Number of Iterations
    outer_loop_iteration_count = int(math.ceil((range_upper_bound - range_lower_bound) / range_step))
    # Inner Loop Same since range bounds and step for outer and inner are the same
    inner_loop_iteration_count = outer_loop_iteration_count
    # Inner Loop Runs Outer Loop Times
    number_of_iterations = outer_loop_iteration_count * inner_loop_iteration_count
    print(f'{number_of_iterations} Iterations')
    # List of Iteration Counts (0 indexed)
    iterations_as_list = list(range(0, number_of_iterations))
    print(iterations_as_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```